# Informar al usuario de que se ha añadido un objeto con un CreateView en Django

Tags: django, listview, views

Buenas.

Estoy añadiendo objetos en mi base de datos, haciendo uso de vistas basadas en clases genéricas, en concreto CreateView.

Por ejemplo, estoy añadiendo objetos del modelo Alumno, de manera que en models.py tengo:

```
class Alumno(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lista-alumnos')
```

De esta forma, cuando añado un objeto, se vuelve a la vista llamada lista-alumnos, que es una ListView que muestra todos los objetos alumnos.

Además, la vista para crear o añadir alumnos es:

```
class AlumnoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Alumno
    fields = '__all__'
```

Además, la plantilla alumno_form.html es:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block maincontent %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }} <!-- as_table, as_ul -->
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
        <a class='btn' href="{% url 'lista-alumnos' %}">Cancelar</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Sin embargo, mi intención es que una vez que he añadido un alumno y le doy a submit, pueda informar al usuario de que se ha grabado el nuevo alumno, además de llamar a lista-alumnos.

Puede que me haya explicado muy mal, pero en realidad necesito un comportamiento similar al módulo de admin de Django, ya que cuando grabas un objeto, vuelve a la lista de objetos de ese modelo pero además, en la parte superior de la pantalla se muestra el mensaje "Se añadió con éxito el alumno Jesús Rodríguez"

Muchísimas gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que quieres son dos cosas distintas. Por un lado quieres que al tener éxito al guardar te mande a una página determinada  y __la segunda pregunta__ es cómo mandar mensajes a las páginas. Por lo tanto __debes__ editar tu publicación para que solo exista una pregunta, y hacer una nueva para la segunda. Sigue esta guía __[mcve]__. Por el momento, tu pregunta es __demasiado amplia__ y puede ser cerrada.

Comment: Al final mirando ejemplos he conseguido realizarlo, con el campo success_message de SuccessMessageMixin. Lo que no sé es si editar la pregunta, eliminarla o poner la solución, por si a alguien le viene bien.

El código resultante de la vista para crear alumnos, quedaría:
    class AlumnoCreate(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
        model = Alumno
        fields = '__all__'
        success_message = 'El alumno %(nombre) se ha grabado correctamente'

Comment: Voy a nominar la pregunta para reapertura. Por favor agrega, en cuanto puedas, una respuesta, con el mayor nivel de detalle posible. Te lo agradezco mucho. Gracias a usuarios como tu, crece esta comunidad.